# How can I get discord bot on Replit to send random image from a file when called?

Tags: python, image, file, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to have my bot send a random image inside a folder whenever the command #React is called. Here's what I've tried so far but the bot doesn't send anything:
[Bot function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pv30.png)

I've already uploaded the folder containing all the images to Replit. Any assistance would be appreciated!

Thank you all.

Comment: Please don't attach images of code, include it in your question as properly formatted code. See [edit] for information on how to do this

Answer (score -1):

Add your images into a list and then use `random` to generate a random index number

```
images = ["T1.jpg","T2.jpg","T3.jpg","T4.jpg","T5.jpg"]
await message.channel.send(file=random.choice(images))
```

Comment: You can simplify this by using `random.choice(images)` instead of `random.randint(0,(len(images)-1))`

Comment: So I implemented the "await message.channel.send(file = random.choice(images))" line into my code however now it's giving me the following error:

Comment: Ignoring exception in on_message

Comment: InvalidArgument('file parameter must be File')

Comment: i think you should point it to the location of the file, like this ./T1.jpg